# android - two footers have white space between them

Tags: android, header, footer, spacing

I've created two seperate footers, though the issue still arose even with just one. There is a white space on the tops and bottoms of the footers. The images themselves are perfect and have no white space in them. they are supposed to be stacked on top of one another with absolutely no spacing.

Here is a screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/403iht0fgp25s49/Screenshot%202015-03-04%2010.19.09.png?dl=0

What do I do in order to make these have no white spacing between them?

Thank you

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapFragment" >

  <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
      >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_footer_booktestdrive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bookatestdrivefooter" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_footer_website"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/footer" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>



 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:gravity="center" >

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:src="@drawable/map1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your layout:
Delete the `linearlayout` and align one image `bottom`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapFragment" >

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_footer_booktestdrive"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bookatestdrivefooter"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_footer_website"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/footer"
            />
    </LinearLayout>   

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/map1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Tell us if it worked.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you, but it didn't work. Please see the screenshot

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/by2c3hgqwbn54pt/AAAWOe5ktsqdSdw2kgk64JoNa?dl=0

Comment: Can you post the images? ill try to fit it on the layout directly. Also ill see if may be an image width problems. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. I've put the images in the same dropbox folder as the link above. Here's the link again:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/by2c3hgqwbn54pt/AAAWOe5ktsqdSdw2kgk64JoNa?dl=0

Comment: Add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` really worked for me.

Comment: I added android:scaleType="fitXY", it filled up the space but stretched both the images vertically in order to do so.